# Adding a Custom List to Cells in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have gone through the [tutorial](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-custom-list-for-sorting-and-filling-data-HA010222142.aspx) on how to create a custom list, but it doesn't say how to add it to the cell.

What I want to do is to add a listbox to a cell:

i.e.

Cell A1 has a drop down button to choose an item from a list, that was created in the Custom List. Like this image (note this is not my image): [Drop Down Box in Cell](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/docs/c1truedbgrid/ImagesExt/image27_26.png).

So in the end, what I want to do is to click on the arrow (in the cell) and choose an item, instead of typing it every time.

Is there a way I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a drop-down list and can be created easily in Excel 2007.

[image]

Using Data Validation Tools, you can add a drop-down list to your sheet.

1. To create a list of valid entries for the drop-down list, type the
   entries in a single column or row without blank cells.
2. You may want to sort the data in the order that you want it to
   appear in the drop-down list.
3. If you want to use another worksheet, type the list on that
   worksheet, and then define a name for the list.
4. Select the cell where you want the drop-down list.
5. On the Data tab, in the Data Tools group, click Data Validation.
   [image]
6. In the Data Validation dialog box, click the Settings tab.
7. In the Allow box, click List.
8. To specify the location of the list of valid entries, do one of the
   following: If the list is in the current worksheet, enter a reference to your list in the Source box. If the list is on a different worksheet, enter the name that you defined for your list in the Source box. In both cases, make sure that the reference or name is preceded with an equal sign (=). For example, enter =ValidDepts.
9. Make sure that the In-cell dropdown check box is selected.
10. To specify whether the cell can be left blank, select or clear the
     Ignore blank check box.
11. Optionally, display an input message when the cell is clicked.
12. Specify how you want Microsoft Office Excel to respond when invalid
     data is entered.

You can get details from the source below.

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/insert-or-delete-a-drop-down-list-HP010072599.aspx)

Comment: The same thing with Excel 2003 can be done with these instructions: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Drop-Down-List-from-a-Range-of-Cells-in-Excel-2003